# Manipulate White Spacing in PHP when converting SQL to Text in Unity

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

quick question. I am using Unity3d to make a top-down 2D Platformer with a Leaderboard score ranking scene. Basically I have everything setup already, I have the database saved in a free webhosting server which I can access through PHP and convert it to an in-game displayable string in Unity.

The problem is I am a complete beginner using PHP and this is in fact my first time using it, the string created using my PHP looks ugly:

[image]

As you can see, it does not take into consideration the length of the Player's name when printing the number of white spaces. Please take a look at my PHP code:

```
<?php
// Send variables for the MySQL database class.
mysql_select_db("a6263746_Neptune") or die('Could not select database');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `scores` ORDER by `score` DESC LIMIT 15";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);  

for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
{
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     echo $row['name'] . "\t". str_repeat(" ", 40) . $row['score'] . "\n";
}
```

?>

Now, to fix this, I hear you can use str_pad(); to fix this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

So I go on and give it a try and my code ends up looking like this:

```
<?php
// Send variables for the MySQL database class.
mysql_select_db("a6263746_Neptune") or die('Could not select database');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `scores` ORDER by `score` DESC LIMIT 15";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);  

for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
{
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     echo str_pad($row['name'] , 10) . str_pad($row['score'], 12 " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
}
```

?>

But when I use this PHP code, it returns the error:

[image]

Can anyone help me with what the proper syntax and format is with applying this code to PHP? Thanks in advance guys, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like unity can render html. Have you tried making 2 separate columns to render text in?

Comment: Since you're a beginner in PHP I really recommend to switch from mysql_* functions functions to PDO or mysqli_* functions. Because msyql_* are deprecated.

Comment: You could also use a fixed width (monospace) font like system

Comment: Yes I have tried, and after 8 hours of work it works but with a ton of errors and it doesn't do what I want it to do. Here's what I did: string[] Array = TrueDatabase.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); to convert the string to a list that separates the words using spaces.

Comment: THen I put the words into separate lists using: for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++){

    if(i%2 == 0) {
     
     Names.Add(Array[i]);
     //Debug.Log (Array[i]);
     
    }

    else {

     Scores.Add(Array[i]);
     //Debug.Log (Array[i]);

    }
   }

Comment: THen I converted the lists to a arrays for size limits:    NameArray = Names.ToArray();
   ScoreArray = Scores.ToArray();

Comment: And lastly, I made those arrays into strings again:    NameList = string.Join("\n", NameArray);
   ScoreList = string.Join("\n", ScoreArray); But when I display it, it acts funny and displays random elements from my strings...

Comment: @Andy Gee, can you tell me more about fixed width (monospace)? Thanks

Comment: Sure, it'll be an option in unity I guess. If you're using fixed width fonts the string padding will work perfectly as each character is exactlky the same width. Technically making columns out of text.

Comment: But what happens if there are different numbers of characters in a row?

Comment: Work out how many total columns, logest name and longest score possible then decide where you want each column. Personally I would align all scores right and all names left. I'll make some PHP to help after dinner.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Im swamped. About time I have dinner too. Haha.

Comment: is that your real login credentials? dont show real username password on questions

Comment: You're right. Edited them out. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unity select a mono space font, some available here: http://www.fonts2u.com/category.html?id=18
Next change your code to layout as text with spacing.

```
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);  

//Settings
$total_width = 30;                          //Total number of monospace columns
$left_padding = 3;                          //Add optional left and right padding
$right_padding = 3;
$left = str_repeat(" ", $left_padding);     //3 spaces
$right = str_repeat(" ", $right_padding);   //3 spaces


for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $name_width = strlen($row['name']);         //width of the name
    $score_width = strlen($row['score']);       //width of the score

    //calculate the middle padding
    $middle_padding = $total_width - ($left_padding + $name_width + $score_width + $right_padding);
    $middle = str_repeat(" ", $middle_padding); //more spaces!
    echo $left.$row['name'].$middle.$row['score'].$right . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hey again, I tried something similar: <?php
mysql_select_db("a6263746_Neptune") or die('Could not select database');
 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `scores` ORDER by `score` DESC LIMIT 15";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
 
    $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);  
 
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
    {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
         $username = $row['name'];
         $userscore = $row['score'];
         echo str_pad($username, 15, " ");
         echo str_pad($userscore, 18, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
    }
?>

Comment: But even if there are now equal numbers of characters per row and it is arranged accordingly, the positions of the scores still look disorganized because of the differing widths of each character. Looks like the mono space font should do the trick. If my code doesn't work i'll use yours. Thanks a lot. Cheers!